# Просьба прояснить: почему при сборке в gulp тегу html присваиваются классы(возможно генерируется каким-то плагином)?

Tags: html, gulp

В принципе не на что это не влияет,
хочется узнать природу происхождения этих классов
и не приводит ли это к каким-либо ошибкам.

Один из классов всегда одинаковый и выглядит как идентификатор: `idc0_350`

К примеру добавляются такие:

```
class="qwldycr idc0_350" 
class="aefwqqei idc0_350"
class="mliyv idc0_350"
```

и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, по умолчанию класс не должен присваиваться, значит у тебя где то в настройках или в плагине есть это присваивание. Я бы посмотрел для начала туда

Comment: Какие пакеты подключены к сборке?

Comment: "browser-sync",  "del", "fs", "gulp", "gulp-autoprefixer", "gulp-clean-css", "gulp-cli", "gulp-file-include",  "gulp-fluent-ffmpeg", "gulp-fonter-unx", "gulp-group-css-media-queries", "gulp-htmlmin", "gulp-if", "gulp-imagemin","gulp-newer"", "gulp-notify", "gulp-plumber", "gulp-pug", "gulp-rename", "gulp-replace","gulp-sass", "gulp-size", "gulp-sourcemaps", "gulp-svg-sprite", "gulp-ttf2woff", "gulp-ttf2woff2",  "gulp-util", "gulp-version-number", "gulp-webp"","gulp-webp-html-nosvg",  "gulp-webpcss",  "gulp-zip",  "sass",  "swiper", "vinyl-ftp", "webp-converter", "webpack", "webpack-stream"